# Apache Dispatcher Sling Dynamic Include (SDI) with TTL

Tags: apache, caching, aem, suse

I'm Using Adobe AEM 6.1. Now I want to use Sling Dynamic Include 3.0.

1. Installed the Sling Dynamic Include on the Publish instance
2. I configured the Dispatcher with help of the following Documentation:

   - https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/platform-repository/using/sling-dynamic-include-technical-video-setup.html
   - https://github.com/Cognifide/Sling-Dynamic-Include

I also added the `/enableTTL "1"` in the dispatcher.any file inside of the cache tag, and added the headers in the cache tag

```
 /headers
 {
    "Cache-Control"
    "Content-Disposition"
    "Content-Type"
    "Expires"
    "Last-Modified"
    "X-Content-Type-Options"
 }
```

The Sling Dynamic Include works good. But the Problem is that the TTL Parameter is ignored. And I know I need AEM Dispatcher 4.1.11 and higher to use TTL. Well I'm using Dispatcher version 4.2.2 with an apache 2.2. Maybe I need an higher apache version that the TTL works?

My understanding of the TTL is, that I want to cache a file for 5 min, so in this 5 min, the users always get the cached document, and after this 5 min the dispatcher delete the old cached file, and get a new one.

Have somebody any idea? How can I check what is going wrong? 
I don't get an error or something, just the TTL param is ignored.

Here The Working SDI Include in my HTML
[image]

I think with the path is something wrong. After the "...ttl.html" is the resource Type "/cbz/components/elements/bookingcalendar". I think it should end by the .html. But I don't know why this is happen.

The Config

[image]

Comment: I haven't used Apache 2.2 in a while but as far as I know, the dispatcher is compatible with both Apache 2.4 and Apache 2.2. Just make sure you [download the right version](https://www.adobeaemcloud.com/content/companies/public/adobe/dispatcher/dispatcher.html). They're listed separately for Apache 2.4 and Apache 2.2. 
Can you post your OSGi config for SDI?

Comment: I have added my config.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the HTML rendered, you're dealing with a synthetic resource.

As far as I know, until SDI version 3.1.2, the caching of such resources with TTL was not possible (see [SLING-7785](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-7785) due to the way the resource type was appended as a suffix. Although, to be honest, I'm not sure why you do get a cached document at all. It's hard to tell without looking at the dispatcher cache config.

I suggest you try upgrading SDI to 3.1.2 or higher and using the newly provided configuration.

On a side note, Cognifide no longer maintains the SDI documentation you linked to. The project has been donated to Apache Sling and the most up-to-date docs can be found on the [official Apache Sling Website](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/dynamic-includes.html)

I've noticed that the official docs do not yet describe this feature so I raised [SLING-7914](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-7914). If you get it working, feel free to contribute a short how-to guide.